# Error 500 on Laravel 4 Blade templates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using the latest version of Laravel 4, and whenever I try to load a page that is a blade template I get an Error 500. However views that do not use blade load properly. I made sure that the directory and sub directories of app/storage are writeable by the server, and it still made no difference. My code is as follows:

Route

```
Route::any('/', 'Users@login');
```

Controller (users.php)

```
public function login()
{
    return View::make('users.login');
}
```

View (login.blade.php)

```
       {{ 'hello' }}
```

Comment: Check /var/log for your webserver's error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are passing the data to the view? When using controllers you can return a view with some data usin the "with" method

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. You may have problems in configuration.